# Practical play in KRPvKQ central pseudo-fortresses?

Tags: endgame, defense, 50-move-rule, fortress

A rook and a pawn sometimes draw against a queen, if a proper fortress can be set up. These are possible to learn to defend, and it's also possible to learn how to attack these with a queen when the defence is incorrect.

Only some pawn positions can lead to a fortress, as this illustration from wikipedia shows.

[image: Fortress]

The 2nd, 6th, 7th rank and knight pawn fortresses are all manageable to learn, as well as the a3 and h3 special cases. Same goes for learning how to attack in the rook pawn cases.

What about the central squares?

I was using tablebases to see how the strong queens wins in those cases, but apparently this is far from trivial. Especially interesting are how these positions can be **pseudo-fortresses**

```
    [FEN "8/1K6/8/2P5/2R5/7k/7q/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

The queen is eventually able to capture the rook, but not within the 50 move rule.

At a high level, the strategy seems to be humanly understandable:

1. The attacking side tries to win a tempo through a series of queen checks, using each free tempo to get the king closer. When the king has arrived, the defending king must eventually separate from the rook.
2. The defending side tries to keep the king and rook close to the pawn, hiding the king in the upper left part of the board where the queen has limited space.

The specifics not so much. What is the mechanism that gives a free tempo? Unlike KQvKP on the 7th rank where the king is forced in front of the pawn, the reason the attacking side can "waste" a move on the king is not obvious. And how does the forcing apart manoeuvre work?

The defending side too does not have an easy to comprehend way of moving. To get out of check various rook blocks and king moves are used, and it's hard to tell which one to pick. The tablebases do however tell that picking the wrong one can lead to a faster loss, no longer holding out for 50 moves.

Is this possible to hold/attack practically?

Inaccurate play seems to liquidate in several ways. Possibly, the pawn can be lost, leading to a lost but still tricky queen vs. rook position. The rook can be lost early, threefold repetition is very much on the cards, and perhaps the defending side can advance the pawn into a true fortress, or even promote? Attempting to do so resets the move counter though is objectively a tablebase loss, but perhaps easier to defend for a human?